# SQL error:Incorrect syntax near ',' using select in insert

Tags: sql

I'm trying to execute this SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO ItemAssignments(EmployeeId, ItemId, ModifiedOn) 
    (SELECT Id FROM Employees WHERE Acronym ='ardsd',2,'2019-07-10 09:03:55.830'),
    (SELECT Id FROM Employees WHERE Acronym ='bsadf',2,'2019-07-10 09:03:55.830'),
    (SELECT Id FROM Employees WHERE Acronym ='casde',3,'2019-07-10 09:03:55.830'),
    (SELECT Id FROM Employees WHERE Acronym ='dasas',3,'2019-07-10 09:03:55.830');
```

Error between `SELECT` expression and next parameter.

I've tried to write SELECT into brackets - but that didn't help.

Please tell me what can I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one SELECT with a UNION as the source:

```
INSERT INTO ItemAssignments(EmployeeId,ItemId,ModifiedOn) 
SELECT id, 2, '2019-07-10 09:03:55.830'
FROM Employees 
WHERE Acronym in ('ardsd', 'bsadf')

UNION ALL

SELECT id, 3, '2019-07-10 09:03:55.830'
FROM Employees 
WHERE Acronym in ('casde', 'dasas');
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want logic like this:

```
INSERT INTO ItemAssignments(EmployeeId, ItemId, ModifiedOn) 
    SELECT Id,
           (CASE WHEN Acronym in ('ardsd', 'bsadf') THEN 2
                 ELSE 3
            END),
           '2019-07-10 09:03:55.830'
    FROM Employees
    WHERE Acronym in ('ardsd', 'bsadf', 'casde', 'dasas')
```